# Как в поток filestream передать часть файла?

Tags: c#, filestream

Есть файл доступный на чтение, добавляю его в поток FileStream я так:

```
 FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(path);
 FileStream fileStream = fInfo.OpenRead();
```

Но файл очень большой. Как мне в поток отправить только данные с миллионного байта до 2 миллионного байта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых: [Использование объектов, реализующих IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects).

Во-вторых: не до конца понятно, зачем вам это, но если в лоб решать, то [FileStream.Seek](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.seek?view=net-5.0).

```cs
long length = 1000000;
long start = 1000000;
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
using FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path);
fileStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
```

Comment: по поводу во первых, есть файлы с необработанными данными и размером доходящим до сотен гигабайт. Иногда нужно быстро к ним обращаться считывая только определенный кусок. А за ответ спасибо.

Comment: Обычно считывают кусками с самого начала файла вытягивая и обрабатывая данные. Здесь же ответ именно про вытягивание куска с определенного по определенный байт а не про "поблочное" считывание всего файла....

Comment: @polsok да без разницы, сколько там гигабайт. Смысл в последовательном чтении. И почему вам оно не подходит - только вам известно. В общем, вы захотели странного, странное я и ответил.

Comment: @aepot, т.е. мы в принципе не сможем считать часть файла не с начала. А как можно тогда реализовать данное действие. Искать блоки на диске?

Comment: @polsok блоки на диске ищет файловая система, что именно вам нужно и зачем? Задачу то какую решаете? Но вообще Seek работает.

Comment: @polsok - _т.е. мы в принципе не сможем считать часть файла не с начала_ - с чего это? Код в ответе именно это и делает. `Seek` не читает данные, а просто устанавливает указатель, откуда читать. PS: ещё можно использовать свойство `Position` - эффект ровно тот же.